# creating a new variable using the def command in python

Tags: python

I am trying define a command that creates a new variable based on one of the arguments given for the command. For example:

```
def NewEntry(Variable,Variable_Entry,Column,Row):
    Variable = StringVar()
    Variable_Entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 15, textvariable = Variable)
    Variable_Entry.grid(column = Column, row= Row)
```

So far I have been unsuccessful as it keeps saying that the entry at position Variable hasn't been defined yet (Which is true, as that is what I am trying to accomplish). Is there any good way of getting this done?

Comment: why are you taking variable as a parameter and then defining it?

Comment: If you're defining all these variables inside the function, just use Column and Row as parameters.. `def NewEntry(Column,Row):` . Also, do not uppercase first letter of variables

Comment: I *think* I understand what you're trying to ask, but your terminology is so confused that I think you're just way out of your depth here. You should study how functions work in command-line programs first, before you try to create a GUI.

Comment: I'm trying the take a parameter and define it as a variable because right now the same basic operations gets done multiple time for different variables. Having the defining of a variable and operations done on said variable happen in one command would made the code as it is right now a lot more readable, understandable and mostly, a lot shorter. And lastly; yes, I am way in over my head, so my nomenclature might not be correct, my apologies for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set variables by passing them in as arguments. It doesn't work because it doesn't make any sense. What you want is more like this:

```
def NewEntry(column, row):
    variable = StringVar()
    variable_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=15, textvariable=variable)
    variable_entry.grid(column=column, row=row)
    return variable, variable_entry
```

Then, when you *call* this function, you save its return values in whatever variable names you like:

```
var, var_entry = NewEntry()
```

Answer (score 1):

To make a global variable, do this (albeit very ugly and not really nice):

```
def newEntry(Variable): # Variable should be a string
    globals()[Variable] = StringVar()
```

However, you shouldn't do this. You won't know the variable afterwards!

If you want to store GUI elements, or multiple unknown items, use built-in data types, such as lists and dictionaries. They are much easier to use, and widely accepted.