# I want to allocate new variable inside def

Tags: python

I want to create new variable in def,
but that is not recommended.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30517398/creating-a-new-variable-using-the-def-command-in-python\](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30517398/creating-a-new-variable-using-the-def-command-in-python%5C)
My code that I want to run is below,

```
# I imported some libraries,
from bindsnet.network.nodes import Input
import bindsnet
network = Network()

# then I create new variable "input_layer"
input_layer = Input(n=100)
network.add_layer(layer=input_layer, name="A")
```

Now, I need to create many of input layer.
So, I want to make it as a def that works exactly the same as the above, for ease of repetition.
like this

```
def test_add_network(layer_name, node_type, n, node_name):
    layer_name = node_type(n)
    network.add_layer(layer = node_type, name = node_name)

# then run,
test_add_network(input_layer_test, Input, 100, "A")
```

I got Error,

```
NameError: name 'input_layer_test' is not defined
```

I understand what this error wants to say.
Here I face same problem,(pasted earlier)
[creating a new variable using the def command in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30517398/creating-a-new-variable-using-the-def-command-in-python)

how do I solve this

Comment: You can't, in CPython, create a variable dynamically in the caller. You can dynamically create global variables, but **you shouldn't**. Why doesn't the solution I'm that question work for you?

Comment: Your error gives you nice hint.

Comment: Use `return` to create an object inside a function and return it the caller. Also, I suggest you should go through some tutorials to learn about functions and variables in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass in the name of the variable you want created. Instead, `return` the new value from your function and assign it to the variable name in the calling scope:

```
def test_add_network(node_type, n, node_name):
    layer_name = node_type(n)
    network.add_layer(layer = node_type, name = node_name)
    return layer_name

# then run,
input_layer_test = test_add_network(Input, 100, "A")
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove 'layer_name' from the parameters. It's not an input, it's an output. Just make your function return layer_name at the end, call it and assign the result to `input_layer_test`

```
def test_add_network(node_type, n, node_name):
    layer_name = node_type(n)
    network.add_layer(layer = node_type, name = node_name)
    return layer_name

# then run,
input_layer_test = test_add_network(Input, 100, "A")
```